# How can I automatically autoscale the plots in Simulink's Scope during a simulation?

Tags: matlab, simulink

When I want to look at signals in the scope during a simulation, I might have to click on the `Autoscale` button whenever the signal is out of view. Is there a way to automatically autoscale so you can always see the whole signal during the simulation?

[Simulink 8.3, Matlab R2014a]

Comment: Interesting question! Sometimes I change limits of the axes in scope and it works properly - It show all simulation time at OX and I can see all the generated signal. But much often I can see only a little part of plot and it changes so fast, that I need to press autoscale every second... I still can see some relation between this behaviors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that by writing a function to ask Simulink to automatically autoscale and call it every N seconds. The function I got are from [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26326-simulink-scope-autoscale), it just basically triggers the autoscale button :

```
 % find all scope blocks as MATLAB figures:
set(0, 'showhiddenhandles', 'on')
scope = findobj(0, 'Tag', 'SIMULINK_SIMSCOPE_FIGURE');
for i=1:length(scope)
  % this is the callback of the "autoscale" button:
  simscope('ScopeBar', 'ActionIcon', 'Find', scope(i))
end
set(0, 'showhiddenhandles', 'off')
```