# Autoscale Scope after each simulation step

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently debugging a `MATLAB`function in my `Simulink` model. Therefore, I use the single stepping functionality. I have several scopes I want to observe after each step (started by clicking the button inside one of the scopes) and at the moment I have to click the autoscale button each and every time in all of the scopes.

Is there a way to do that autoscaling automatically each time the simulation pauses? I tried to put the code from the [Matlab Answers page](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26326-simulink-scope-autoscale) as suggested in [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437444/how-can-i-automatically-autoscale-the-plots-in-simulinks-scope-during-a-simulat) into the `PauseFcn` model callback, but it didn't work.

Do you have any idea to solve that?

[Matlab R2015b, Simulink 8.6]

Comment: Hey c-a, placing TAB's code in the `StartFcn` callback function of a simple test model perfectly worked for me for single stepping as you only need to call it once.

Comment: Placing it in the `PauseFcn` callback will cause the scopes to close and re-open at every step if you leave this code inside: `for x=1:length(bh); set_param(bh(x),'Open','off'); end`

Comment: If I copy & paste TAB's code into the `StartFcn` callback it simply opens all scopes, but if I start stepping it doesn't autoscale

Comment: you're right. It's no longer working today, another Figure window pops up when I start the simulation. Probably played too much around with the other script as well and had a different workspace at that moment.